# Refactoring database after migrating table

Tags: sql-server, query-refactor

I'm creating a new staging database, into which I intend to migrate several tables from the old database. These tables are referenced in functions and stored procedures. If I were doing things manually, I would just migrate the tables, and then modify the functions by replacing the old table name with the new table name. I'm thinking there must be a more automated way of doing this though.

Has anyone done something similar; what tools have you used to help refactor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the tables in the old database with [synonyms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-synonym-transact-sql) that point to the location in the new database.

This not only minimizes the code change, it gives you a single place to manage the references to objects in other databases.

Comment: +1 for an elegant answer - we used to do something like this for customisations - we only wanted to pay for one Oracle (sorry :-) ) dev server licence so we used synonyms to point to different tables for different clients - all on  the one server! I honestly don't know if it was worth it - a real PITA to administer! Time =  money too!